# Как добавить в сессию массив?

Tags: массивы, сессия, php

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь сохранить массив в сессию, чтобы не мотаться к базе данных.
Например, у пользователя есть выбранные элементы (квартиры, которые ему нравятся),
и надо как-то

1) сохранить в сессии массив;
 2) изменить в сессии массив.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

Спасибо.

Comment: В рамках фреймворка или на чистом php?

Что вам мешает сделать старт сессии и погрузить массив на прямую в неё?

`$_SESSION['my_array'] = $arr;`

Comment: чистом php. Спасибо